# Login system in C has flaw on verification

Tags: c

I have implemented a login system in C, where the user has three chances to enter the correct user_id and password, if you finish all, the program close.

The problem now is that if the first attempt failed, and the second attempt key incorrect
credentials, the system wont authenticate the user, it only works on first attempt if the credentials is correct.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char user_id[50];
    char name[50];
    char password[50];
    char email[50];
    char role[50];
} users;

int main() {
    login_menu;

    return 0;
}

void login_menu() {
    printf("Login page");
    FILE *users_file = fopen("users.txt", "r");

    int authenticated = 0;
    int login_attempts = 0;

    const int max_login_attempts = 3;

    while (login_attempts < max_login_attempts) {
        users user;

        int valid_user_id = 0;
        char user_id[50];
        char password[50];

        printf("Please enter your User ID (TP number or Tutor code)  down below: \n");
        scanf("%s", user_id);
        printf("Please enter your password down below: \n");
        scanf("%s", password);

        if ((user_id[0] == 'T' && user_id[1] == 'P') || (user_id[0] == 't' && user_id[1] == 'p')) {
            valid_user_id = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                user_id[i] = user_id[i + 2];
            }
        } else if ((user_id[0] == 'T') || (user_id[0] == 't')) {
            valid_user_id = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                user_id[i] = user_id[i + 1];
            }
        } else if ((user_id[0] == 'A') || (user_id[0] == 'a')) {
            valid_user_id = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                user_id[i] = user_id[i + 1];
            }
        }

        if (valid_user_id) {
            // use while loop to read the file line by line
            while (fscanf(users_file, "%s %s %s %s %s \n", user.user_id, user.name, user.password,
                          user.email, user.role) != EOF) {
                if (strcmp(user.user_id, user_id) == 0 && strcmp(user.password, password) == 0) {
                    authenticated = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (authenticated) {
            fclose(users_file);
            printf("Login successful %s (%s) !\n", user.name, user.role);
            dashboard_menu(user);
            break;
        } else {
            login_attempts++;
            printf("Login id or password is incorrect, %d attempts left. Please try again.\n", (3 - login_attempts));
            printf("Invalid c");
        }
    }

    if (authenticated == 0) {
        printf("Max login attempts reached. Exiting program.\n");
    }

    fclose(users_file);
}
```

here is the txt file `users.txt`, for the data of the users

```
988955 John 123456 admin@apu.edu.my admin 
265663 Mary 123456 marry@apu.edu.my tutor 
009650 Peter 123456 peter@apu.edu.my tutor 
544654 James 123456 james@apu.edu.my tutor 
577001 Johnny 123456 john@apu.edu.my tutor 
683357 David 123456 david@apu.edu.my tutor
```

**Examples**
[image]

[image]

Comment: Note, in the real world you never store the user password. Instead you create a hash of the user password and store the hash. When the user attempts to login, you hash what is given as the password and compare it to the stored hash. That way if your password file is compromised -- they only get a hash and not the actual password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you read through all of your `users_file` via `fscanf()` on the first attempt, so then if the user needs to make a second attempt, the seek-position of `users_file` file-handle is already at the end of the file, so `fscanf()` won't return any more of the file's contents.

The easy fix is just to call [rewind(users_file)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/rewind) before doing your loop-of-fscanf() calls -- the `rewind()` call will move the read-position of the file-handle back to the beginning of the file, so you can read through all the entries in the file again, the same way you did the first time.  (alternatively, you could call `fclose()` on your file-handle than then re-open the file with another call to `fopen()`, that would have a similar effect)

Btw note that your calls to `scanf()` are extremely unsafe -- if the user is malicious (or just careless), he can enter more than 50 characters as his input, and cause `scanf()` to write past the end of your `user_id` and/or `password` arrays, corrupting your program's stack and potentially allowing the user to seize control of the program's execution.  It's highly recommended that you replace all calls to `scanf("%s", blah);` with something that takes the length of the output-buffer as an argument instead (e.g. `fgets(blah, sizeof(blah), stdin);`), so that any potential buffer-overwrites can be avoided.

Comment: maybe you can elaborate more on `fgets(blah, sizeof(blah), stdin);`. like how do i implement it

Comment: Google "man fgets" and follow the instructions there.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of issues in this program of yours. First off, you need to add `()` to the end of a routine if you'd want to call it. Right now, you just have `login_menu` as part of your `main` which is valid C which is why the compiler doesn't complain and you never know.

Additionally, you are using `login_menu` before you declare it. If you want to skip the declaration, make sure your `main` is at the very bottom. If not, have a declaration at the top right after your includes and your pre-processor definitions. A more aggressive compiler might not even proceed with compiling this unless it know what `login menu is`.

Your program should look like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char user_id[50];
    char name[50];
    char password[50];
    char email[50];
    char role[50];
} users;

void login_menu();

int main() {
    login_menu();

    return 0;
}

void login_menu() {
    printf("Login page");
    FILE *users_file = fopen("users.txt", "r");

    int authenticated = 0;
    int login_attempts = 0;

    const int max_login_attempts = 3;

    while (login_attempts < max_login_attempts) {
        users user;

        int valid_user_id = 0;
        char user_id[50];
        char password[50];

        printf("Please enter your User ID (TP number or Tutor code)  down below: \n");
        scanf("%s", user_id);
        printf("Please enter your password down below: \n");
        scanf("%s", password);

        if ((user_id[0] == 'T' && user_id[1] == 'P') || (user_id[0] == 't' && user_id[1] == 'p')) {
            valid_user_id = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                user_id[i] = user_id[i + 2];
            }
        } else if ((user_id[0] == 'T') || (user_id[0] == 't')) {
            valid_user_id = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                user_id[i] = user_id[i + 1];
            }
        } else if ((user_id[0] == 'A') || (user_id[0] == 'a')) {
            valid_user_id = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                user_id[i] = user_id[i + 1];
            }
        }

        if (valid_user_id) {
            // use while loop to read the file line by line
            while (fscanf(users_file, "%s %s %s %s %s \n", user.user_id, user.name, user.password,
                          user.email, user.role) != EOF) {
                if (strcmp(user.user_id, user_id) == 0 && strcmp(user.password, password) == 0) {
                    authenticated = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (authenticated) {
            fclose(users_file);
            printf("Login successful %s (%s) !\n", user.name, user.role);
            //dashboard_menu(user);
            break;
        } else {
            login_attempts++;
            printf("Login id or password is incorrect, %d attempts left. Please try again.\n", (3 - login_attempts));
            printf("Invalid c\n");
        }
    }

    if (authenticated == 0) {
        printf("Max login attempts reached. Exiting program.\n");
    }

    fclose(users_file);
}
```

Additionally, since you've not provided the definition for `dashboard_menu()`, I had to comment it to compile and check this program. If you have it defined elsewhere, please declare it at the top along with other declarations.

Lastly, use some of the flags that help you put good programming practice into action and compile your program like so:

`# cc -ggdb -Wall -O0 -pedantic login.c -o login`

Your issues with `scanf` have been pointed to by Jeremy but please keep these things in mind as well for your next assignments.